# Thymeleaf - trying to use Java's replaceAll function in 'data-th-with'

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a div tag in my html page with a `data-th-with` attribute.  The old working code was this:

```
<div class="facetSubMenu"
         data-th-with="searchMenuInput=${#strings.replace(searchMenu.getInputName(), '/', '-')}"
```

Now I learned I need to not only replace forward slashes but basically strip out any non-alphanumeric characters.  So I quickly learned that Thymeleaf's replace function does not handle regex.  So it looks like I will need to use Java's replaceAll function.

So now I have this code:

```
<div class="facetSubMenu"
         data-th-with="searchMenuInput=${searchMenu.getInputName().replaceAll('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')}"
```

[image]

Picture added to show where the errors are occurring.  Hovering over each red error gives `Cannot resolve 'getInputName'` and `Cannot resolve 'replaceAll'` respectively.  Any ideas how I can use the replaceAll function correctly in this manner?

Comment: I don't think I am.  In what way?

Comment: I'm getting my info from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555971/571723

Comment: I know that Java has a `replaceAll` that takes a regex, that is why I'm trying to switch to it.

Comment: What is the error? That expression works for me.

Comment: Yep, appears to be just an issue with my IDE flagging a bunch of non-existent errors.